# program to access GUI application

Tags: user-interface, automation

I have a commercial application specific to my field that is GUI based but does not offer batch mode. I don't have the source code for this application either. Is it possible to write a program that enables me to access the original application.

Basically, I'm looking for a program which will enable me read values from a text file and enter them at appropriate locations in the GUI application and click appropriate buttons in the GUI application.

Is it possible to do such a thing? If yes, any references are very much appreciated.

thanks

Comment: That depends on your OS / platform. On Windows for example you can use  AutoIt ( https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/ ) and the like.

Comment: The [help/on-topic] clearly says *Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow*. See in particular item #4 in the numbered list on that page.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is an entire list of tools you can use.  Eggplant is one I have seen used for GUI's.  Selenuim is good for web page automation.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_GUI_testing_tools